# PHP - take data from html textarea row after row into variables

Tags: php, html, forms, textarea

I have a HTML form and there is a textarea let's say like this:

```
link1
link2 
link3
```

I would like to take the text from the text area row after row through PHP file so it will in the end be like this:

```
$var1 will be "link1"
$var2 will be "link2"
$var3 will be "link3"
```

important - this variables must be saved in php - whole form is in html file

EDIT: this can be done with array too, so i will have ["link1", "link2", "link3"]

EDIT2: if this is done with array i would like to acces it with indexes like in JS or other languages so "$array[0]" for example... (i know its not done like this in php)

Comment: So explode text by a newline.

Comment: Well explode makes an array, OP wants separate variables by some odd reason. But array is a far better solution though.

Comment: maybe i could try this with array, could you please show me how this can be done with array? i googled php explode text but i dont use php daily, this is just for easy json file update

Comment: ok i got it now and did it

Comment: Mark it as solved? Posting the solution to your problem would be beneficial to other users who may visit this question in the future too.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use a `foreach`.

Let's say you have a `textarea` tag.

```
<textarea name="lyrics"></textarea>
```

You can access it's value:

```
$lyrics = $_POST['lyrics'];
$text = trim($lyrics);
$textAr = explode("\n", $text);
$textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');
```

Use `foreach`

```
foreach ($textAr as $line)
{
    echo $line;
}
```